# edit bash command gcc to compile and execute in one line

Tags: c, macos, bash, gcc

I want to know if this is possible:

if you put `gcc filename.c` you will compile `filename.c` in `a.out` file
and if you put `./a.out` you will execute the file.

The composite version it's

```
gcc filename.c && ./a.out
```

I want edit this command in bash_profile to do this in one short command line.

`gcc filename.c` do this `gcc filename.c && ./a.out`

Comment: And what will happen if the build fails?

Comment: Im in the case you codes its perfect or if your code fails yo can do an echo with the problem

Comment: @UniCell probably a message to stderr and an exit... The use of `&&` here seems perfectly reasonable

Comment: @arco444 my question it was somehow sarcastic because he could easily implement that.

Comment: i dont know how to implement this. because yo need to promt the file name

Comment: @UniCell I don't follow - nothing needs to be implemented. It would be _exactly_ the same as running `gcc filename.c` and have it fail

Comment: @Rslnautic Your best bet is to write a function

Comment: @arco444 i'm a little noobie. Is it a function shell?

Comment: You could write a .bat file that will automatically execute that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a function:

```
gccrun () {
    gcc "$1" && ./a.out
}
```

Be careful, though: what if someone uses full path to the C file as a parameter?

Makefiles are usually used for this kind of stuff.

```
a.out: file.c
    gcc $<

run: a.out
    ./a.out
```

`make run` would run `a.out` recompiling it if its source has changed since the last compilation or doesn't exist.

Comment: I want do this now: gcc filename.c -o filename && ./filename.out

Comment: @Rslnautic: Read about Parameter expansion in bash and get it done (`${1%.c}`).