# How to run C program without having to run 'gcc filename.c' and 'a.exe '

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

When i type the command `gcc filename.c` a new file 'a.exe' is created, then i have to run `a.exe` to get my program to run.

Is there a way just to type one command to run my program or can you run a C program without having a new .exe file being created?

I use gcc version **gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0**

(Complete beginner with C)

Comment: `gcc filename.c && ./a.exe`

Comment: You never mention C++, so why the C++ tag?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ allows for function and operator overloading.  C++ has string, vector and map data structures.

Comment: @drescherjm is that the standard way of running C files?

Comment: It's a way of combining the execution of 2 processes. `&&` executes the second program if the first one completed successfully.  `&&` works for this in windows, linux and other systems. More on this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the `.c` file directly - you have to compile it into an executable (using `gcc` or whatever compiler).  However, you don't have to compile it every time you want to run it - you only have to compile it after first creating it and after you make any changes.  So you can run `gcc` once, then run `a.exe` multiple times.

You can name the executable something other than `a.exe` if you wish using the `-o` option:

```
gcc -o prog filename.c
./prog
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a .bat file that does everything for you. For example:

```
build.bat
  gcc %1.c -o %1.exe
  %1.exe
```

This will build and run the file for you:

```
build hello
```

will compile and run hello.exe for you.

Comment: You should never blindly run programs that compile with warnings. If you are going to try to automatically run a program after compilation, you should enable warnings (you should always enable warnings), but you should also enable `-Werror` so that compilation fails when there are warnings. [Here is an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861500/6879826) that talks about a solution I have used on Linux.